# Trying to use the value of a cell for criteria in COUNTIF

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc, countif

I've constructed a gradebook in LibreOffice Calc, and I'm trying to keep track of how many students have scored an A, B, etc., on assignments. Currently, I have the grades for an assignment in a single column. The grades are displayed in terms of points (not percentages, so the total number of points available is not necessarily 100). I am trying to construct a cell in the column that will count the number of cells representing the grades if the cell is >= 0.9 × (total number of points), and the total number of points is also in a cell in the same column, but I keep getting an error. So far I've tried the following:

```
=COUNTIF(E2:E25, ">="0.9*E27)
```

but no luck.

After reading some articles on Open Office, I tried the following

```
=COUNTIF(E2:E25, ">="&E27)
```

which did not throw an error, but is not comparing it to the quantity desired.

I've also tried

```
=COUNTIF(E2:E25, ">=0.9*"&E27)
```

and it just produces 0.

Does anyone know if this type of thing is possible to do within `COUNTIF`, or do I actually need to construct an additional cell where I put in `0.9*E27` and just reference that cell?

Comment: Your first form is nearly correct: it should be `=COUNTIF(E2:E25, ">="&0.9*E27)` (you omitted the `&`).

Answer (score 3):

Your third form is nearly right. 
It should be

```
=COUNTIF(E2:E25, ">="&0.9*E27)
```

— you got the order wrong.

The issue is that, for the relationship operators (`>`, `>=`, `<`, `>=`,
`<>` (the bizarre way of expressing “not equal” in spreadsheets) or `=`),
the second argument to `COUNTIF` must be a text string:

> 

#### Syntax:

**`COUNTIF(test_range; condition)`**

  **`test_range`**
  is the range to be tested.

**`condition`** may be:

- a number, such as `34.5`
- an expression, such as `2/3` or `SQRT(B5)`
- a text string

**`COUNTIF`** counts those cells in **`test_range`**
that are equal to **`condition`**,
unless **`condition`** is a text string that starts with a comparator: 
**`>`**, **`<`**, **`>=`**, **`<=`**, **`=`**, **`<>`**. 
In this case **`COUNTIF`** compares those cells in **`test_range`**
with the remainder of the text string
(interpreted as a number if possible or text otherwise). 
For example the condition “**`>4.5`**” tests if the content of each cell
is greater than the number 4.5,
and the condition “**`<dog`**” tests if the content of each cell
would come alphabetically before the text **`dog`**.
Source: [Documentation / How Tos / Calc: COUNTIF function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_COUNTIF_function) 
<sub>(it’s the same in Excel and LibreOffice)</sub>

So, if, for example, cell `E27` contains 60,
then you want to count the cells that contain values ≥ 54
(because 90% × 60 = 54). 
So you need to pass `COUNTIF` a string argument of `>=54`. 
So you need to *compute* `54` and append it to `>=`. 
Use `0.9*E27` to compute `54`,
and then `">="&0.9*E27` to do the string concatenation.